# question on disowning process from python executable in zsh

Tags: python, zsh

I'm encountering some problems when trying to run a process
in background and disown it in `zsh` with the `&!` shortcut.

I'm no expert of either `zsh`, nor `python`,
so it might very well be that I'm missing something obvious here.

The executable is the following `python` program, call it `test.py` (I'm using `python2.7.15`):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import time

for idx in range(5):
  print(idx)
  time.sleep(2)

with open('test.txt','w') as ofile:
  ofile.write('done')
```

With some trial-and-error, I noticed the following:

1. if I run `./test.py &!` and then logout, the process does not complete successfully
   (I check this by looking at the presence and content of the file `test.txt`);
   it looks like it's not getting disowned, and logging out causes it to stop;
2. if I run `./test.py > test2.txt &!`, and then logout,
   it does work as expected (again, based on the presence of the `test.txt` file);
3. if I comment out the the second line (`from __future__ ..`), modify the `print` statement,
   run `./test.py &!`, and then logout, it also works as expected.

What am I missing? And would there be a way to make 1. work, without resorting to 2. or 3.?

Comment: What do you mean by "modify the print statement"?

Comment: I just meant using `print idx`, instead of `print(idx)`.

Comment: That shouldn't have any effect. I suspect a race condition with your login shell closing your script's standard output before it has completed writing to it.